# Found "Undefined in Document Collection" when try to fetch and update Collection from Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i am still newbie and still self learning using react & firebase, please help me with this code.

I try to ***fetch and update data*** from ***firestore colection data*** using form with react & material-ui,

after i update useEffect function, no Error found it just not working as my expectation.

[attached file firestore location picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuUy6.jpg)

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

 // material-ui
 import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
 import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
 import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
 import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

// firebase
 import { useFirebase } from '../../../components/FirebaseProvider';
 import { useDocument } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

import AppPageLoading from '../../../components/AppPageLoading';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';
```

### the function

```
function EditProduk({ match }) {

const { firestore, user } = useFirebase();
const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
const produkTraining = firestore.doc(`userdoc/${user.uid}/training/${match.params.trainingId}`);

const [snapshot, loading] = useDocument(produkTraining);

const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: '',
    trainer: '',
    price: 0,
    description: ''
});

const [error, setError] = useState({
    name: '',
    trainer: '',
    price: '',
    description: ''
})

const [isSubmitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (snapshot) {

        setForm(currentForm => ({
            ...currentForm,
            ...snapshot.data()
        }));
    }
}, [snapshot]);

const handleChange = e => {

    setForm({
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })

    setError({
        ...error,
        [e.target.name]: ''

    })
}

const validate = () => {
    const newError = { ...error };

    if (!form.name) {
        newError.name = 'Training name must be filled';
    }
    if (!form.trainer) {
        newError.trainer = 'trainer name must be filled';
    }
    if (!form.price) {
        newError.price = 'price must be filled';
    }
    if (!form.description) {
        newError.description = 'description must be filled';
    }
    return newError

}


const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const findErrors = validate();

    if (Object.values(findErrors).some(err => err !== '')) {
        setError(findErrors);
    } else {
        setSubmitting(true);
        try {
            await produkTraining.set(form, { merge: true });
            enqueueSnackbar('Data has been saved', { variant: 'success' })
        }
        catch (e) {
            enqueueSnackbar(e.message, { variant: 'error' })
        }
        setSubmitting(false);
    }

}

if (loading) {
    return <AppPageLoading />
}

return <div>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h1">Edit Training: {form.name}</Typography>
    <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <form id="produk-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
                <TextField
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    label="Training Name"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    value={form.name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    helperText={error.name}
                    error={error.name ? true : false}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                />
```

### firestore rules

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /userdoc/{uid} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid;

    match /training/{trainingId}{
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

please give me some advise

Comment: @AtinSingh I'm not sure abou this. Checkout this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-leavitt-r957x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to test the firestore rules, there is a good option for that (firestore simulator, you can find it in the firebase consol) in which you can specify so many different parameter and test whether you can access data or not based on a specific scenario.

as far as I understand you want to fetch data from firestore, put it into a form, possibly edit the data and save it back to the database.

The error your are receiving has nothing to do with firestore or its rules, because it seems the **`form`** variable is undefined at the moment.

Try this:

```
async function EditProduk({ match }) {
```

...

```
const [snapshot, loading] = await useDocument(trainingDoc);
```

Comment: Its right sir, i want to fetch data from firestore, put it into a form, possibly edit the data and save it back to the database

Comment: @jawara I think the problem is that you would not wait on useDocument, So I guess after that line, useEffect will set the form variable to undefined. use async operation for that.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the error you need to replace `value={form.name}` with `value={form && form.name && form.name}`

as well as

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        setForm(snapshot.data());
    }
}, [snapshot]);
```

Comment: Getting the data is a separate problem. To help with that open a new question and show us how `useFirebase()` and `useDocument()` work and log `match.params.trainingId` so that we know this is a valid reference.

Comment: i thing you  are right sir, but i still not found the solution, u can see the picture which i attach, is not targeting the ID Collection but make a new Collection id with "Undefined" collection ID

Comment: You just changed the entire question? That is not cool. If I answered your original questions please award methe answer and open a new questions. You can't just keep changing your question, all the responses will be out of context for anyone else reading this in the future. I disapprove.